# How to use different reporters in scalameter?

Tags: scala, scalameter

I want to try using some reporters in my benchmark for function `Main.lengthOfUUID`.

```
object Main {

  def lengthOfUUID(s : Int) = {
    val x = List.fill(100000)(1)
    val sum = x.sum
  }
}
```

Firstly I tried `ChartReporter`

```
import org.scalameter.api._
import org.scalameter.picklers.Implicits._

object UUIDBench extends Bench[Double] {


  lazy val executor = LocalExecutor(
    new Executor.Warmer.Default,
    Aggregator.min[Double],
    measurer)
  lazy val measurer = new Measurer.Default
  lazy val reporter = ChartReporter(ChartFactory.XYLine())
  lazy val persistor = Persistor.None
  val sizes: Gen[Int] = Gen.range("size")(1, 8, 1)
  val ranges: Gen[Range] = for {
    size <- sizes
  } yield 0 until size
  performance of "Batches" config (
    exec.benchRuns -> 4
    ) in {
    measure method "main" in {
      using(sizes) in { s =>
        Main.lengthOfUUID(s)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it throws a error

```
Error:(14, 36) ambiguous implicit values:
 both object BigIntIsIntegral in object Numeric of type scala.math.Numeric.BigIntIsIntegral.type
 and object IntIsIntegral in object Numeric of type scala.math.Numeric.IntIsIntegral.type
 match expected type Numeric[T]
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
  lazy val reporter = ChartReporter(ChartFactory.XYLine())
Error:(14, 36) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Numeric[T]
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
  lazy val reporter = ChartReporter(ChartFactory.XYLine())
Error:(14, 36) not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit evidence$1: Numeric[T])org.scalameter.reporting.ChartReporter[T] in object ChartReporter.
Unspecified value parameter evidence$1.
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
  lazy val reporter = ChartReporter(ChartFactory.XYLine())
```

I saw this [issue](https://github.com/scalameter/scalameter/issues/90). Code there is not available now, but it is said to use `HTMLReporter`, so I tried it

```
lazy val reporter = Reporter.Composite(
    new RegressionReporter(
      RegressionReporter.Tester.OverlapIntervals(),
      RegressionReporter.Historian.ExponentialBackoff() ),
    HtmlReporter(true)
  )
```

But got similar errors

```
Error:(15, 5) ambiguous implicit values:
 both object BigIntIsIntegral in object Numeric of type scala.math.Numeric.BigIntIsIntegral.type
 and object IntIsIntegral in object Numeric of type scala.math.Numeric.IntIsIntegral.type
 match expected type Numeric[T]
    new RegressionReporter(
Error:(15, 5) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Numeric[T]
    new RegressionReporter(
Error:(15, 5) not enough arguments for constructor RegressionReporter: (implicit evidence$1: Numeric[T])org.scalameter.reporting.RegressionReporter[T].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$1.
    new RegressionReporter(
Error:(18, 17) ambiguous implicit values:
 both object BigIntIsIntegral in object Numeric of type scala.math.Numeric.BigIntIsIntegral.type
 and object IntIsIntegral in object Numeric of type scala.math.Numeric.IntIsIntegral.type
 match expected type Numeric[T]
    HtmlReporter(true)
Error:(18, 17) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Numeric[T]
    HtmlReporter(true)
Error:(18, 17) not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit evidence$1: Numeric[T])org.scalameter.reporting.HtmlReporter[T] in object HtmlReporter.
Unspecified value parameter evidence$1.
    HtmlReporter(true)
```

How should I use these reporters?

Comment: I copied your code and run it with no issues. What's `do_job.main`? Why do you even pass `null`? That is not very idiomatic Scala.

Comment: that's some placeholder for object I need to benchmark. `null` is passed because `main` function takes args `Array` as parameters.

Comment: `Array.empty` is better than. Regardless as I said I copied your code and compile it with no issues. Would you mind updating the question with your current code? It says error at line 15... for which file? what line?

Comment: @mfirry I added code for example.

Comment: You said you're not using `ChartReporter`... would you mind putting the code you're actually running now? It's very confusing.

Comment: @mfirry Where did I said that I am not using it? I wanted to use it and post the errors which I got during this. After this I tried `HTMLReporter` and got similar errors. All of this I posted above. Actually running is only `LoggingReporter` because `Chart` and `HTML` don't work. Sorry if some misunderstanding happened

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227279/discussion-between-mfirry-and-nourless).